# Can we add chat status to the main site?

Tags: feature-request, chat

I've noticed that on [other sites](https://math.stackexchange.com/), on the right-hand side under "Blog" and "Hot Meta Posts" there is a chat status - people in the room, last user to comment, and the time at which the last comment was posted.

Is that feature just for some sites, or is there a way we can turn it on for us? I wish people would use chat more often, but I feel like it's a self-feeding cycle where nobody is on chat, so nobody goes to chat, so there's never any updates, so there's no reason to check chat, so nobody is ever on chat.

Comment: FWIW, following your link, I can not see a chat status. Under "Hot Meta Posts" I just have Custom Filters, Watched Tags and Ignored tags, and then the HNQs.

Comment: @Greenonline - Yup, maybe it's a feature they killed? Googling around I couldn't find anything (except this question lol), so then I started looking around for images of rhte StackExchange UI and found [this post on ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/An-example-of-Stack-Overflow-post-postId34672987-here-demonstrates-a-question-with_fig3_328767554) that shows `131 People Chatting` on the right side, shows the names of the chat rooms `JavaScript` and `PHP`, who the last person was to say something in those rooms, and when.

Comment: I asked for this (wow) 6.5 years ago now. The post pictured in the link I gave above is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34672987/5171120), and it's from 7 years, 4 months ago. In the image, the post was asked 1 year, 3 months ago, which means the chat status was in place for about 6 months after I asked this question. It would still be nice - sometimes people go days or weeks without a response in our chat, but I think that's because there's no notification of activity there. For me personally, unless I recently interacted in the chat room I can go weeks without checking it.

Comment: Thanks for the ResearchGate image, interesting. Yes, I saw your meta Q and thought it would be useful to have on the 3D Printing site as well. Maybe the feature has actually been dropped/scrapped..? Shame. However, I saw that @V2Blast had changed the tag, so was hopeful that maybe it was still an active feature request.

Comment: I don't know the exact logic behind when the chat box/info is displayed in the right sidebar; [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) is probably your best bet if you want to understand the logic behind that, or want to propose changes to it.